# How to read the value from a TreeItem / DataItem using Windows Application Driver / C#?

Tags: c#, dataitem, windows-application-driver

I am having trouble accessing the text within a DataItem.
Is there a way to get the text ["Repair Exceptions(0)" etc] for each node in the TreeItem using [windows application driver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver)?

**xml**

```
<Group>
    <TreeItem Name="Node0">
        <DataItem Name="Item row 0"/>
    </TreeItem>
    <TreeItem Name="Node1">
        <DataItem Name="Item row 1"/>
    </TreeItem>
</Group>
```

**What Data looks like on the screen**

[image]

**Further Investigation**

---

Using Microsoft Inspect tool provided the details that I am looking for is the value.

**Path:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x64\inspect.exe

**ControlType:** UIA_DataItemControlTypeId

Comment: Not sure what you expect. If you traverse the xml in your example, how could you possibly get "repair Exceptions"?

Comment: @JonasH the xml doesn't show what is displayed on the screen.

Comment: that is my point. What should the logic be to transform the data in the xml file to the thing displayed on the screen? Simply count xml rows for exceptions/warnings? What would a xml-file that contains exceptions/warnings look like?

Comment: i can't understand your explaination either. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pull it out using the **element.Text**.

```
var elements = session.FindElements(By.XPath($"//DataItem"));

foreach(var dataItem in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dataItem.Text);
}
```

> "Repair Exceptions (0)"
>   "Input Exceptions (0)"